# Using JavaScript, How do you output multiple user inputs using objects in a class?

Tags: javascript, class, object

I am having difficulty displaying the results of a form on the webpage. I am using a class, a constructor and also trying to assign the user inputs to an objects. The issue is I am only able to display one user input, whenever I try to do more than one the output is undefined.

```js
class person {
  constructor(addFirstName, addLastName) {
    this.firstname = addFirstName;
    this.lastname = addLastName;
  };
};

function DisplayInfo() {
  first = document.getElementById("addFirstName").value;

  let person1 = new person(first);
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = person1.firstname;

  last = document.getElementById("addLastName").value;

  let person2 = new person(last);
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = person2.lastname;
};

showInput.addEventListener("click", DisplayInfo);
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter your first name:</legend>
  <input type="text" id="addFirstName">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter your last name:</legend>
  <input type="text" id="addLastName">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter your class:</legend>
  <input type="text" id="addClass">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter your section:</legend>
  <input type="text" id="addSection">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter your role:</legend>
  <input type="text" id="addRole">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <p id="display"></p>
  <button id='showInput'>Show: Person/Class/Role</button>
  <script src="form.js"></script>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: You should just create one person: `let person = new person(first, last);`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't create a separate person for the first and last names. Create one person with both names. Then show them both in the display area.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(addFirstName, addLastName) {
    this.firstname = addFirstName;
    this.lastname = addLastName;
  };
};

function DisplayInfo() {
  let first = document.getElementById("addFirstName").value;
  let last = document.getElementById("addLastName").value;
  let person = new Person(first, last);
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = `${person.firstname} ${person.lastname}`;
};

showInput.addEventListener("click", DisplayInfo);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>FORM</title>

</head>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter your first name:</legend>
  <input type="text" id="addFirstName">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter your last name:</legend>
  <input type="text" id="addLastName">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter your class:</legend>
  <input type="text" id="addClass">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter your section:</legend>
  <input type="text" id="addSection">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter your role:</legend>
  <input type="text" id="addRole">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <p id="display"></p>
  <button id='showInput'>Show: Person/Class/Role</button>
  <script src="form.js"></script>
</fieldset>


</html>
```